# Programmatically set Validation Options for a TcxTextEdit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

`ValidationOptions` under `TcxTextEdit.Properties` contains `evoRaiseException`, `evoShowErrorIcon` and `evoAllowLoseFocus`.

How would one go about setting these to either `True` or `False`?

For example:

```
procedure TfrmMain.cxTextEdit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if cxTextEdit1.Text = EmptyStr then
    begin
      evoRaiseException := true; ????
    end
end;
```

Comment: Surely this is the wrong way to perform validation. By setting validation options on exit. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TcxTextEdit.Properties.ValidationOptions` is defined as:

```
TcxEditValidationOptions = set of (evoRaiseException, evoShowErrorIcon, evoAllowLoseFocus);
```

`TcxTextEdit.Properties.ValidationOptions` being a `set` it can contain one or more values defined in the enumeration.

This allows to add only a value to the set without affecting the others:

```
procedure TForm1.cxTextEdit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if cxTextEdit1.Text = EmptyStr then begin
    cxTextEdit1.Properties.ValidationOptions := cxTextEdit1.Properties.ValidationOptions + [evoRaiseException];//adds a value
  end;
end;
```

These are valid assignments:

```
cxTextEdit1.Properties.ValidationOptions := []; //empty

cxTextEdit1.Properties.ValidationOptions := [evoRaiseException, evoShowErrorIcon]; //assigns 2 values to the set

cxTextEdit1.Properties.ValidationOptions := cxTextEdit1.Properties.ValidationOptions - [evoRaiseException]; //removes a value
```

This checks if a set contains a value:

```
if evoRaiseException in cxTextEdit1.Properties.ValidationOptions then
  . . .
```

You don't assign all the values to `True` or `False` but the values are added to the set or they are not.

The elements of a `set` are ordinals whose values can be obtained through the `System.Ord` function:

```
anIntVariable := Ord(evoShowErrorIcon);
```

When no explicit value is assigned to an element in a `set`, the elements start with `0`.

A value can be explicitly assigned to an element in a `set` like follows:

```
TMyCustomSet = set of (mcsTriangle = 3, mcsHexagon = 6, mcsNonagon = 9);
```

See also [Structured Types (Delphi) - Sets](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Structured_Types#Sets), [System.Ord](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Ord) and [System.Include and System.Exclude](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/SetIncludeExclude_(Delphi)) usage example.